# How to avoid "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-state

I am using react typescript, redux toolkit and material UI. I am getting this error in while calling the API:

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
> at renderWithHooks (http://127.0.0.1:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-QJV3R4PZ.js?v=8a99eba5:12178:23)
> at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://127.0.0.1:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-QJV3R4PZ.js?v=8a99eba5:14921:21)
> at beginWork (http://127.0.0.1:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-QJV3R4PZ.js?v=8a99eba5:15902:22)....

I am providing my code below:

**EditMenuPermission.tsx**

```
//EditMenuPermission.tsx
//other imports 
/* ++++ Redux Imports ++++ */
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { AppDispatch, RootState } from "src/redux";
import { roleActions } from "../roles/RolesActions";
/* ---- Redux Imports ---- */

const EditMenuPermission = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<RoleMenuItem[]>(
    [] as RoleMenuItem[]
  );
  const [selectedIds, setSelectedIds] = useState<number[]>([] as number[]);
  const role = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.roles.selected) as Role;
  const [roleMenus, setRoleMenus] = useState<RoleMenuItem[]>([]);
  if (role?.menus) {
    try {
      const parsedMenus = JSON.parse(role.menus) as RoleMenuItem[];
      setRoleMenus(parsedMenus);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error parsing role menus:", error);
    }
  }

  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(roleActions.findOne(id as unknown as number));
  }, [dispatch, id, role?.id]);

  console.log("previousMenus:", roleMenus, "selected:", selected);

  const handleCreatePayload = async () => {
    const updatedMenus = [...roleMenus];
    selected.forEach((selectedItem) => {
      const existingItemIndex = updatedMenus.findIndex(
        (menu) => menu.id === selectedItem.id
      );

      if (existingItemIndex !== -1) {
        updatedMenus[existingItemIndex] = selectedItem;
      } else {
        updatedMenus.push(selectedItem);
      }
    });
    setRoleMenus(updatedMenus);
    const payload = {
      name: role.name,
      is_active: true,
      is_deleted: false,
      menus: JSON.stringify(updatedMenus),
    };
    console.log("updated Menus:", updatedMenus);

    const updateRole = await dispatch(roleActions.update(role.id, payload));
    console.log(updateRole);
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <AdminTitleContainer>
        <AdminTitle variant="h5">Role Permission</AdminTitle>
      </AdminTitleContainer>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={9}>
          <Box>
            <RoleMenuTrees
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
              selectedIds={selectedIds}
              setSelectedIds={setSelectedIds}
              roleMenus={roleMenus}
            />
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            startIcon={<AddCircle />}
            onClick={handleCreatePayload}
            sx={{ position: "fixed" }}
          >
            Save
          </Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default EditMenuPermission;
```

**RoleMenuTrees.tsx**

```
//other imports
/* ++++ Redux Imports ++++ */
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { AppDispatch, RootState } from "src/redux";
import { roleActions } from "src/features/admin/roles/RolesActions";
/* ---- Redux Imports ---- */
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useRoleMenuTree } from "src/hooks/useMenuTree";
import { SingleRoleMenuDTO } from "src/features/admin/roles/RolesDTO";
import { menuActions } from "src/features/admin/menu/MenuActions";
import {
  AllMenu,
  Permission,
  PermissionType,
  RoleMenuItem,
  SingleRole,
} from "../../RoleDTO";

type RoleMenuTreesProp = {
  selected: RoleMenuItem[];
  setSelected: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<RoleMenuItem[]>>;
  selectedIds: number[];
  setSelectedIds: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number[]>>;
  roleMenus: RoleMenuItem[];
};

const RoleMenuTrees = ({
  selected,
  setSelected,
  selectedIds,
  setSelectedIds,
  roleMenus,
}: RoleMenuTreesProp) => {
 

  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  const { id } = useParams();

  const roleMenusJSON = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.roles.selected as SingleRole
  )?.menus;


  const allMenus = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.menus.list
  ) as AllMenu[];


  useEffect(() => {
  
    dispatch(menuActions.getList());
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  /*++++ merging roleMenus + allMenus starts +++++*/
  const mergedMenus = allMenus?.map((menu) => {
    const matchingMenu = roleMenus.find(
      (roleMenu: RoleMenuItem) => roleMenu.id === menu.id
    );
    if (matchingMenu) {
      const { permissions: _, ...rest } = { ...menu, ...matchingMenu };
      return rest;
    } else {
      const permissions = JSON.parse(menu.permissions) as Permission[];
      const permissionType = {} as PermissionType;
      permissions?.forEach((permission) => {
        const { key } = permission;
        permissionType[key] = false;
      });
      const { permissions: _, ...rest } = {
        ...menu,
        permission_type: permissions,
        ...permissionType,
      };
      return rest;
    }
  });

  console.log("mergedMenus:", mergedMenus);

  /*---- merging roleMenus + allMenus ends ----*/

  const createRoleMenuTree = useRoleMenuTree(
    mergedMenus as unknown as SingleRoleMenuDTO[]
  );
  const tree = createRoleMenuTree.tree;
  const mapMenu = createRoleMenuTree.mapMenu;

  return (
    <Box>
      <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: "#fafafa" }}>
        {/*++++ Menu List starts ++++*/}
        <TreeView
          className="TreeView"
          defaultExpandIcon={
            <ChevronRightIcon sx={{ fontSize: "1.5rem !important" }} />
          }
          defaultCollapseIcon={
            <ExpandMoreIcon sx={{ fontSize: "1.5rem !important" }} />
          }
        >
          {tree?.map((data) => (
            <Box key={data.id}>
              <RoleMenuTree
                data={data as unknown as RoleMenuItem}
                selected={selected}
                setSelected={setSelected}
                selectedIds={selectedIds}
                setSelectedIds={setSelectedIds}
                mapMenu={mapMenu}
              />
            </Box>
          ))}
        </TreeView>
        {/*---- Menu List ends ----*/}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default RoleMenuTrees;
```

I tried removing the dependencies in useEffect. But the error still persists.

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

The issue here is enqueueing a React state update ***outside*** the React component lifecycle as an unintentional side-effect. This code is called any time the `EditMenuPermission` component renders, and if `role.menus` is truthy, will enqueue a state update and trigger the component to rerender. This is the render looping you see.

```js
const role = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.roles.selected) as Role;
const [roleMenus, setRoleMenus] = useState<RoleMenuItem[]>([]);

if (role?.menus) {
  try {
    const parsedMenus = JSON.parse(role.menus) as RoleMenuItem[];
    setRoleMenus(parsedMenus);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error parsing role menus:", error);
  }
}
```

## Solution

Move the `roleMenus` state update into the component lifecycle.

### Naive Solution

A naive approach would be to use the `useEffect` hook to synchronize the `roleMenus` state to the current `role.menus` value.

```js
const role = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.roles.selected) as Role;
const [roleMenus, setRoleMenus] = useState<RoleMenuItem[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (role?.menus) {
    try {
      const parsedMenus = JSON.parse(role.menus) as RoleMenuItem[];
      setRoleMenus(parsedMenus);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error parsing role menus:", error);
    }
  }
}, [role?.menus]);
```

### Improved Solution 1

This would work, but it's generally considered a React anti-pattern to store derived "state" into React state. The current `roleMenus` value is easily computed from the current `role.menus` value. You should keep in mind that just about 100% of the time if you find you've coded a `useState`/`useEffect` coupling that this is when you should use the `useMemo` hook instead.

```js
const role = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.roles.selected) as Role;

const roleMenus = useMemo<RoleMenuItem[]>(() => {
  try {
    return JSON.parse(role.menus) as RoleMenuItem[];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error parsing role menus:", error);
    return [];
  }
}, [role?.menus]);
```

### Improved Solution 2

If this is something you select and compute often from Redux, I'd suggest considering moving the logic into a selector function.

Example:

```js
const selectRoleMenus = (state: RootState) => {
  const role = state.roles.selected;

  try {
    return JSON.parse(role.menus) as RoleMenuItem[];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error parsing role menus:", error);
    return [];
  }
};
```

```js
const role = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.roles.selected) as Role;
const roleMenus = useSelector(selectRoleMenus) as RoleMenuItem[];;
```

### Further Improved Suggestion

And better still, just JSON.parse the role data in the slice reducer function when updating the Redux state so the computation is done only once each time the state is updated instead of each time the state is read.

Answer (score 1):

On high level the setState in the `if` block seems to be the culptrit.

Try moving it to a `useEffect` with `role.menus` as a dependency.

Like the snapshot shown

```
const EditMenuPermission = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<RoleMenuItem[]>(
    [] as RoleMenuItem[]
  );
  const [selectedIds, setSelectedIds] = useState<number[]>([] as number[]);
  const role = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.roles.selected) as Role;
  const [roleMenus, setRoleMenus] = useState<RoleMenuItem[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (role?.menus) {
      try {
        const parsedMenus = JSON.parse(role.menus) as RoleMenuItem[];
        setRoleMenus(parsedMenus);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error parsing role menus:", error);
      }
    }
  }, [role?.menus]);

  ...
```

Comment: I just tried it. It worked like magic. Thank you.  <3 . Can you please elaborate, on how I detect these bugs since the code just looks fine?